# Logstash grok filter to tag bounced messages

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

Summary: I've a few outbound smtp servers and centralized mail logs via rsyslog to a server on which i'm Using logstash, outputting to elasticsearch, searching with kibana.

I would like to tag as "BOUNCED" for Postfix mail log entries like:

```
2013-02-01T16:50:14+02:00 XXSMTPXX postfix/smtp[10879]: BC54A65BD4: to=<xxxx.yyyyyy@zzzz.com.t>, relay=none, delay=0.3, delays=0.01/0/0.29/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=gozdesigorta.com.t type=AAAA: Host not found)
```

the grok filter i've used in logstash.conf is like:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
    tags    => "postfix/bounce"
    pattern => "%{POSTFIXBOUNCE}"
    add_tag => "BOUNCED"
    named_captures_only => true
}
```

patterns file i'm using is https://gist.github.com/4691822

I could not manage to tag those log lines as BOUNCED... What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the pattern as:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} %{HOST} %{SYSLOGPROG}: %{QUEUEID}: to=<%{EMAILADDRESS:to}>, relay=%{RELAY}, delay=%{POSREAL:delay}, delays=%{DELAYS}, dsn=%{DSN}, status=%{STATUS} %{GREEDYDATA:reason}
```

Now i can grok ;)

Comment: Btw, seems like you are getting all `a=b` values using groks. That's not necessary, Just use kv filter. :)